# Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd()) corrupts my image&video files

Tags: c#

I tried to upload image & video files, but using this code all my image & video files are corrupted, how can I decode image & video?

``````````````````````````````````````
public void UploadFile(string SouPath, string DestPath, string Login, string Password)
{           
    try
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(DestPath);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Login, Password);

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(SouPath);
        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd()); // **
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        String FileName = Path.GetFileName(SouPath);
        WriteStoneList("Upload File " + FileName + ".  | Status : " + response.StatusDescription);
        response.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteStoneList("`````````````````````````````````````");
        WriteStoneList(ex.ToString());
    }
}
``````````````````````````````````````

---

i tried to decode image but its not working. and i am getting corrupted image after decoded also.

```
    public static Stream Decode(string Path)
    {
        String text;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path))
        {
            text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            char[] cc = text.ToArray<char>();
            //byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
            //byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(cc,0,cc.Length);
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path);
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            System.Text.Decoder decoder = encoder.GetDecoder();
            int count = decoder.GetCharCount(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            char[] arr = new char[count];
            decoder.GetChars(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, arr, 0);
            text = new string(arr);

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(text);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }
    }
```

---

> i used hear above decode function to get decoded stream

---

```
    public void ConvertFile(string fromPath,string toPath)
    {

        using (Stream source = Decode(fromPath))
        using (Stream dest = File.Create(toPath))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            while ((bytes = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                dest.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`StreamReader` reads **text** streams, of course your images result corrupted inside your destination.

You are overcomplicating things, `WebClient` has already an `UploadFile` method that works out of the box:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Login, Password);
    client.UploadFile(DestPath, "STOR", SouPath);
}
```

Comment: i need to recover my corrupted image because i deleted from local after upload.

Answer (score 0):

image and video files are binary data. encoding them as utf-8 will *always* corrupt this data. there is no need to encode this data, just copy the data to the stream like this:

```
using(var fin = new FileStream(SouPath))
{
    request = fin.Length;
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    fin.CopyTo(requestStream);
    requestStream.Close();
}
```

**not tested**

Comment: i got it but i want to recover my damaged files